# JSON inside JSON-like object javascript

Tags: javascript

I have generated a json-type variable:

```
var jsonLines = [[{"x":"275","y":"231"},{"x":"124","y":"237"}],[{"x":"201","y":"157"},{"x":"275","y":"231"}],[{"x":"215","y":"307"},{"x":"201","y":"157"}],[{"x":"342","y":"188"},{"x":"215","y":"307"}]];
```

I want to parse this JSON-like object and print the corresponding entities. I tried many solutions of similar problems here at SO, but nothing worked on this ( for each loop, by indexing etc.). It'll great if anyone could help me out. Thank you.

Comment: You don't have a JSON string. You have an array with a bunch of objects. No parsing needed. Use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to iterate through it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: This is an array of arrays with objects...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is short for JavaScript Object Notation. What you have there is a Javascript object literal , and it can be treated as such.

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsonLines.length; i++){
    var innerArray = jsonLines[i];

    for(var j = 0; j < innerArray.length; j++){
        var obj = innerArray[j];

        //now you can use obj.x, obj.y etc...
    }
}
```

JSON is heavily based off JavaScript object literals so when it is in actual code and not in a string/text file, it is actually a JavaScript object.

You can break-down the object like so

```
//An Array of...
[
    //Arrays of
    [
        //JavaScript Object Literals
        {"x":"275","y":"231"},
        {"x":"124","y":"237"}
    ],
    [{"x":"201","y":"157"},{"x":"275","y":"231"}],
    [{"x":"215","y":"307"},{"x":"201","y":"157"}],
    [{"x":"342","y":"188"},{"x":"215","y":"307"}]
]
```

Also worth nothing that JavaScript Object property names can be strings

```
var obj1 = {
  a : "someValue"
}

var obj2 = {
  "a" : "someOtherValue"
}

//Both of these objects can access property "a"

obj1.a //someValue
obj2.a //someOtherValue
```